# Google Chart From Php variable

Tags: php, google-visualization, json

I'm trying to make a chart from the google chart api but I can't get my php variable into the script: I get a blank page.

PHP

```
$columns = array(
                array('string' => 'x'),
                array('number' => 'values'),
                array('id' => 'i1', 'type' => 'number', 'role' => 'interval'), 
                array('id' => 'i1', 'type' => 'number', 'role' => 'interval'),
                array('number' => 'OtherValues'),
                array('id' => 'i1', 'type' => 'number', 'role' => 'interval'),
                array('id' => 'i1', 'type' => 'number', 'role' => 'interval') 
                 );
$test = array(
                array( 'a' => array(100, 90, 150,15,10,20)),
                array( 'b' => array(120, 95, 130,20,10,30)),
                array( 'c' => array(130, 105, 140,30,25,35)),
                array( 'd' => array( 90, 85, 95,40,35,45)),
                array( 'e' => array(70, 74, 63,50,45,55)),
                array( 'f' => array(30, 39, 22,60,55,65)),
                array( 'g' => array(100, 90, 150,15,10,20)),

    );
$table['cols'] = $columns;
$table['rows'] = $test;
```

Html view

```
<div id="chart-lines"></div>
<script>
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($table) ?>);


    // The intervals data as narrow lines (useful for showing raw source
    // data)
    var options_lines = {
        title: 'Line intervals, default',
      intervals: { 'lineWidth':2, 'barWidth': 0.5 },

        legend: 'none',
    };

    var chart_lines = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-lines'));
    chart_lines.draw(data, options_lines);
}
</script>
```

Using Google Chrome Javascript Console I get "Uncaught Error: Invalid type: undefined" for every graph with these details:

```
R.Osa
R.ug
(anonymous function)
nj.(anonymous function).d
Ep
drawchart
```

Comment: Blank page means that the chart could not be generated. Check your console for javascript errors and post them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is incorrect for the Visualization API's DataTable constructor.

The correct format for the columns is an array of column objects, where each object has `type` (mandatory), `label`, `id`, and `p` (all optional) properties.  `type` is a string with possible values `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `date`, `datetime`, and `timeofday`.  `label` and `id` are strings.  `p` is an object of column properties.

The correct format for rows is an array of row objects, where each object has `c` and `p` properties.  `c` is an array of cell objects.  `p` is an object of row properties.  The cell objects have `v`, `f`, and `p` properties, where `v` is the value of the cell, `f` is the string-formatted value of the cell, and `p` is an object of cell properties.

Supported properties for all properties objects vary depending on the type of chart(s) you are drawing.

Using PHP's `json_encode` function, associative arrays are translated into objects and non-associative arrays are turned into arrays.  The appropriate structure for your table should look something like this:

```
$columns = array(
    array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'x'),
    array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'values'),
    // each interval should have its own unique id,
    // but leaving them the same won't break anything for your chart as-is
    array('type' => 'number', 'id' => 'i1', 'p' => array('role' => 'interval')),
    array('type' => 'number', 'id' => 'i1', 'p' => array('role' => 'interval')),
    array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'OtherValues'),
    array('type' => 'number', 'id' => 'i1', 'p' => array('role' => 'interval')),
    array('type' => 'number', 'id' => 'i1', 'p' => array('role' => 'interval'))
);

$test = array(
    array('c' => array(
        array('v' => 'a'),
        array('v' => 100),
        array('v' => 90),
        array('v' => 150),
        array('v' => 15),
        array('v' => 10),
        array('v' => 20)
    )),
    // etc
);
$table['cols'] = $columns;
$table['rows'] = $test;
```

Comment: You just made my day sir.