# How do I structure my data into the required format while encoding it into JSON?

Tags: php, google-visualization, json

I am working on an application that needs google charts to display results off MySql Database. How do I structure my data into the required format while encoding it into JSON?

This is my code so far:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("su_data", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chart");    
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
// Generate the output in desired format
$data[]=$row;
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},

        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],

  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},

        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},

        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},

        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},

        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

Comment: What issue you facing with above code ?

Comment: When you output to JSON through PHP you use `json_encode(<your_data>)` E.g. `echo json_encode($data)` - in your case. Do this outside of your "while" loop.

Comment: The issue is that Google Charts API doesn't recognise any other format of the Json file. So I'm unable to view my report.

Comment: I wrote up a description of the DataTable structure and an example showing how it is constructed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760613/google-chart-from-php-variable/21762558#21762558.  If you have any questions about it, I would be more than happy to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chart");    
    $data = array();
    $cols[]=array('label'=>"Month",'type'=>'string');
    $cols[]=array('label'=>"Actual 2013",'type'=>'number');
    $cols[]=array('label'=>"Actual 2014",'type'=>'number');
    $cols[]=array('label'=>"Forecast 2014",'type'=>'number');       


    while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $c[] = array('v'=>$row_result['month'], 'f'=>null);
        $c[] = array('v'=>$row_result['actual_2013'], 'f'=>null);
        $c[] = array('v'=>$row_result['actual_2014'], 'f'=>null);
        $c[] = array('v'=>$row_result['forecast_2014'], 'f'=>null);

        $rows[]=array('c'=>$c);


         $data = array(
         'cols' => $cols,
         'rows' => $rows);
         unset($c);}



   // echo '<pre>';
//      print_r($data);

    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    //echo '<pre>';
//        echo $json_data;
    file_put_contents('sample.json', $json_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know in php but in Java Web application , we use Gson (google library) at controller and At view level we used jersey library to convert objects into JSON